# How to search or filter records from two unidentical SharePoint lists?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have two sharepoint lists that I want to use as the datasource for my 'Search/Filter results' in PowerApps. The problem is that they are not identical, but majority of the columns are same( for e.g Name, DoB and Telephone. List 1 has City but no zipcode, and List 2 has ZipCode but no city). Is it possible to create a 'Union' list or datasource based on the common columns? Any solutions greatly appreciated.
Thank you